# php : how to write $item$i

Tags: php

how to write this correctly?

```
for($i=2;$i<5;$i++)
{
   $items{$i} = $doc{$i}->getElementsByTagName('url'); 
}
```

got an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object

Thanks,
bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test worked for me:-

```
$html1 = "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><p>Doc1 P1</p><p>Doc1 P2</p></body></html>";
$html2 = "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><p>Doc2 P1</p><p>Doc2 P2</p></body></html>";

$doc1 = new DOMDocument();
$doc1->loadHTML($html1);
$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
$doc2->loadHTML($html2);

for($i=1;$i<3;$i++){
    var_dump(${'doc'.$i}->getElementsByTagName('p'));
}
```

So, your code should look like this:-

```
for($i=2;$i<5;$i++)
{
   ${'items'.$i} = ${'doc'.$i}->getElementsByTagName('url'); 
}
```

Unless you mean for $items to be an array, in which case it should look like this:-

```
for($i=2;$i<5;$i++)
{
   $items[] = ${'doc'.$i}->getElementsByTagName('url'); 
}
```

Comment: your code seem to be good...i continu to look why in mine, it doesn't work well...

Comment: Well yours is different, change it to be the same as mine and it will work.

Comment: ok, i found my problem...in the loop, a variable name was false

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
$ndoc = 'doc'. $i;
$items[$i] = $$ndoc->getElementsByTagName('url');
```

or:

```
$ndoc = 'doc'. $i;
$items[$i] = ${$ndoc}->getElementsByTagName('url');
```

Comment: a variable, this is for DOMDocument

Comment: want to do this in a loop:$items2 = $doc2->getElementsByTagName('url');
$items3 = $doc3->getElementsByTagName('url');
$items4 = $doc4->getElementsByTagName('url');

Comment: here the script: for($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
{
   
$ndoc = 'doc'. $i;
$items = 'item'.$i;

$$items = $$ndoc->getElementsByTagName('url');


    for ($j = 0; $j < $$items->length; $j ++) {
        $$items = $$items->item($j);
    
        $item1 = $doc1->importNode($$items, true);
        $res1->appendChild($item1);
    
    }

}

Comment: but i got a problem in the loop...just got only one item for importNode, need all items...searching the reason